# Apache error running java web application

Tags: java, apache, jsp, servlets

I received a Java Web program from my friend and I'm trying to run and understand the code, but I can't seem to run it, here's the error message from Apache log

> 03-Jul-2014 20:33:51.873 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-29] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/毕设] threw exception [The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application] with root cause
>    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:278)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:76)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.generateTldResourcePath(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:215)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:123)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:411)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:469)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1455)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:229)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:200)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:375)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:355)
>       at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:342)
>       at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:403)
>       at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:347)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Is there any way to know what the error is from these logs? If not, what information do I need to provide to know the error?

My web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>main_beforelogin.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
<display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
<servlet-name>itemServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.etc.servlet.itemServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
<display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
<servlet-name>indexServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.etc.servlet.indexServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
<display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
<servlet-name>noticeServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.etc.servlet.noticeServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
<display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
<servlet-name>usrServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.etc.servlet.usrServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
<description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
<display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
<servlet-name>adminLoginServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.etc.servlet.adminLoginServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>itemServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servlet/itemServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>indexServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servlet/indexServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>noticeServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servlet/noticeServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>usrServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servlet/usrServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>adminLoginServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/adminLoginServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>



</web-app>
```

Comment: is there a jstl.jar available in the WEB-INF/lib directory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify if you put the (correct version) of jstl-xxx.jar inside your WEB-INF/lib directory of your application.

Comment: Thank you, I finally got it to run after adding jstl-1.2.jar to the library!
For future reference, how can I know the correct version of jstl to add?
I downloaded the 1.2 and 1.1, tried the 1.2 and it worked straight away, so I didn't bother using the 1.1